# When to provide a bloc in a BlocBuilder()?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to use cubit for flutter counter app. I wanted to know when to provide a Bloc/Cubit to the bloc parameter in the BlocBuilder(). I tried to provide one for the below code but it did not work and got the error :

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CounterCubit> above this CounterPage Widget
```

.

```
class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, int>(
          bloc: CounterCubit(),
          builder: (_, count) => Center(
                child: Text('$count'),
              )),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().increment(),
              tooltip: 'Increment',
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().decrement(),
              tooltip: 'Decrement',
              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is code for cubit.

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  CounterCubit() : super(0);

  void increment() => emit(state + 1);
  void decrement() => emit(state - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation:

> Only specify the bloc if you wish to provide a bloc that will be
> scoped to a single widget and isn't accessible via a parent
> BlocProvider and the current BuildContext.

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  bloc: blocA, // provide the local bloc instance
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

In your case, I would recommend providing your BLoC to the widget tree somewhere above `CounterPage` like this:

```
BlocProvider<CounterCubit>(
  create: (BuildContext context) => CounterCubit(),
  child: CounterPage(),
);
```

Then, inside the `BlocBuilder`, you won't need to specify the `bloc` property:

```
...
body: BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, int>(
  builder: (_, count) => Center(
    child: Text('$count'),
  )),
...
```

Comment: I did not understand "Only specify the bloc if you wish to provide a bloc that will be scoped to a single widget and isn't accessible via a parent BlocProvider and the current BuildContext." When can we make use of the bloc property?

Comment: So, for instance, inside the build() method we can get the BLoC like `final bloc = context.watch<YourBloc>()` and then pass it to BlocBuilder. Technically, that's a working solution, but I have never used it this way.